Issues Connecting Ghidra to GDBServer on Windows
all buttons non active
I'm trying to set up remote debugging for my application on Windows using Ghidra and GDBServer.
trying_connect_to_gdb
GDB successfully connects to GDBServer. However, when I attempt to connect Ghidra using the Debugger, I receive the following error:
Could connect to Trace RMI at localhost/127.0.0.1:1042: Could not receive negotiation request
---------------------------------------------------
Build Date: 2024-Jul-09 1157 EDT
Ghidra Version: 11.1.2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.3.9-hotspot
JVM Version: Eclipse Adoptium 21.0.3
OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
Workstation: DESKTOP-IPF3G77


I verified that port 1042 is open and in use by GDB and GDBServer:
netstat -aon | findstr :1042
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1042         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12536
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1042         127.0.0.1:53076        ESTABLISHED     12536
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53076        127.0.0.1:1042         ESTABLISHED     11952
  TCP    [::]:1042              [::]:0                 LISTENING       17952
  TCP    [::1]:1042             [::1]:53510            ESTABLISHED     17952
  TCP    [::1]:53510            [::1]:1042             ESTABLISHED     6840

I also tried using different ports, such as 1234, but the result is the same. Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Restarted GDBServer on a different port
I’m not sure what might be causing the issue. Has anyone faced a similar situation or knows how to resolve this?
System Configuration:
Windows 10
Ghidra 11.1.2
GDB 11.2
GDBServer
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Are you trying to connect to the same gdbserver connection with both gdb and Ghidra at the same time?
